# CSS make <div> not clickable on mobile device

Tags: css, mobile

I have 2 buttons inside a `<div>` and they are only visible on hover, which works fine on a laptop / desktop PC. The `<div>` is over an image on the site, when you hover over the image, the `<div>` with the buttons inside appears and you can click any of them to go to a location.

The issue is when I view this on a mobile device, If I click the area where any of the buttons are, even though they are not visible, the buttons show, but the link of the button that you clicked over is activated - which I don't want. I want to click on the area and then it display the buttons, and then you click on the button you want to proceed to the link.

I've tried the following but can't get it figured out:

1) Hide the `<div>` by setting `.my-div {z-index:-1;}` as standard and `.my-div:hover {z-index:1;}` when hovered over - which works, but I still have the same issue

2) Setting the `<div>` to `.my-div {visibility:hidden;}` as standard and `.my-div:hover {visibility:visible;}` on hover - again this works but I get the same problem

Is there any other CSS method I can use?

Cheers
Chris

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a demo, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use opacity instead of visibility (Or both). Visibility only makes elements transparent. Opacity removes the ability to interact with the elements.